# FFmpeg keep same video dimension if video height is less than x480

Tags: ffmpeg

The following code im using for video converting:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart -s hd480 output.mp4
```

I want to keep same video dimension for smaller videos. For example keep 640x360 dimension if video height is less than x480.

Is ffmpeg such option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv
   -vf "scale=w='if(gt(ih,480),2*trunc(oh*a/2),iw)':h='if(gt(ih,480),480,ih)'"
   -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!